# Does requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength refers to request sending or receiving the request?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, request, web-config

In the web.config on a client side (client app) I have:

```
 <requestFiltering>
              <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="52428800" maxQueryString="30000" maxUrl="40000" />
 </requestFiltering>
```

On a server side I have:

```
<requestFiltering>
    <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="52428800" />
</requestFiltering>
```

1. Does the client side requestLimits refers to sending or receiving a request?
2. Does the server side requestLimits refers to sending or receiving a request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `maxAllowedContentLength` attribute specifies the maximum size in bytes that a **request** for this web application can have.

So if used in what you call *client application* it still applies to requests made to this client application. And when used in the server application it applies to requests made to this server application. So it doesn't really matter in what kind of web application it is used: all web applications have HTTP requests and this attribute controls the maximum allowed size of this request body for the particular application.

Comment: Can I limit the size of sent requests by the app?

Comment: Which class are you using to make those requests? I am not aware of any way to limit the request size if you are using the standard `HttpWebRequest` class.